# C# complex type initializer compiles without new keyword

Tags: c#

I was recently working on some code, that has changed from using decimal to use a complex type that has the decimal number and a type to represent a fraction. I had to update some tests, and while typing I forgot to add the **new** keyword. The code compiled but the test kept failing, throwing a NullReferenceException. There I realized the missing new and that the property was not initialized. Has anybody an idea why this happening? I could not find anything in the C# lang specification that would explain this.

Here is the code sample:

```
public class Fraction 
{
    public int Numerator { get; set; }
    public int Denominator { get; set; }
}

public class MyDecimal
{
    public decimal? Decimal { get; set; }     
    public Fraction Fractional { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA 
{
    public MyDecimal Value { get; set; }
}

//...

var instance = new ClassA
{
     Value = // new MyDecimal is missing here
     {
         Decimal = 2.0m,
         Fractional = new Fraction 
         { 
               Numerator = 3,   
               Denominator = 4 
         }
     }
}
```

Please note that I'm using C# 6 and VS 2015, but I get the same result also in LINQPad.

If somebody could explain this (I'm looking in your direction Jon Skeet :) ) I would be glad.

Comment: Object-initializer is the term you´re looking for. These initializers are called *after* the constructor of the appropriate class has been called. However in your case as you forgot the `new` keyword you did not call this constructor making `Value` a `NullReference`.

Comment: Why was this question marked duplicate? Clearly it's asking for why the new keyword isn't required, not an actual question about how to use object initializers...

Comment: The difference is that if you ommit the `= new MyDecimal` part, the compiler expects `Value` to already be a reference to an existing object, and will simply navigate into it and attempt to assign properties to it, such as `Decimal` and `Fractional`. That's why you get a NRE. If you add this to your `Value` **declaration**, it will work, but likely not be what you want: `{ get; set; } = new MyDecimal();`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but why is the code compiling like this is another question

Comment: @SelmanGenç Um, no, Lasse also explained that. If `Value` is already initialized (say, in the class constructor of `ClassA`), you don't want to replace it with a different instance, just assign the properties. This is explicitly lined out in the C# specification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object-initializer doesn not really *instantiate* your members.

See the following code:

```
var myInstance = new MyInstance { MyMember = new MyMember { Value = 3 }; }
```

This compiles to:

```
var myMember= new MyMember();
myMember.Value = 3;
var myInstance = new MyInstance();
myInstance.MyMember = myMember;
```

In your case you forgot to *instantiate* `MyMember`, thus the object-intializer tries to *access* that property and assign further values to it. This is due to the fact that object-initializers allways run *after* the appropriate constructor, which wasn´t called in your case. So in your case it compiles to this:

```
var myInstance = new MyInstance();
myMymber.Value = 3;
```

Causing a `NullReferenceException` as `myMember` was never instantiated.

Why does this even compile? Well, I assume the compiler assumes that you instantiate `MyMember` within the constructor of `MyInstance`. It can´t know wheather you actually did this.

```
class Instance
{
    MyMember MyMember = new MyMember();
}
```

Leaving members `null` is of course absoluetely valid.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense entirely, but my question is more in the sense, why this construct compiles, as it clearly should not (or at least there should be a compiler warning)? Or on the other hand, if such construct is possible in the language, what would be the use of it?

Comment: @SlavenVukovic - because it's perfectly valid for an object to have non-null members after it's constructed and before the member initializer executes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That makes completely sense, the compiler can not really verify if or not you have initialized the property in the constructor. I still must admit that it is a bit ugly, and you should be forced to se the new keyword here, but that is another story. Thanks for the answer! Mystery solved.

Answer (score 9):

The C# Specification 5.0 defines object initializer as (*7.6.10.2 Object initializers*):

> An object initializer specifies values for zero or more fields or properties of an object.
>
> ```
> object-initializer:
> {   member-initializer-listopt   }
> {   member-initializer-list   ,   }
> ```

And after the detailed explanation there is an example given which is very similar to your code:

> If Rectangle’s constructor allocates the two embedded Point instances
>
> ```
> public class Rectangle
> {
>   Point p1 = new Point();
>   Point p2 = new Point();
>   public Point P1 { get { return p1; } }
>   public Point P2 { get { return p2; } }
> }
> ```
>
> the following construct can be used to initialize the embedded Point
>   instances instead of assigning new instances:
>
> ```
> Rectangle r = new Rectangle {
>   P1 = { X = 0, Y = 1 },
>   P2 = { X = 2, Y = 3 }
> };
> ```
>
> which has the same effect as
>
> ```
> Rectangle __r = new Rectangle();
> __r.P1.X = 0;
> __r.P1.Y = 1;
> __r.P2.X = 2;
> __r.P2.Y = 3;
> Rectangle r = __r;
> ```

But there is only one difference, the `Point` instances here are initialized inside of the `Rectangle` class which occurs in the constructor of `Rectangle`.

So the syntax is valid by the specification, but you need to make sure `Value` is initialized before using the object initializer to initialize its properties in order to avoid NRE.

Answer (score 3):

The object initializer syntax allows you to initialize an object without creating it first. This is rather important if you want to preserve object identity.

For example, you could make `ClassA.Value` a read-only property, and initialize it in the object constructor:

```
public class ClassA 
{
  public ClassA() 
  {
    Value = new MyDecimal();
  }

  public MyDecimal Value { get; private set; }
}
```

This behaviour is of course explicitly outlined in the C# specification (excerpt from version 5):

> **7.6.10.2 Object initializers**
>
> A member initializer that specifies an expression after the equals sign is processed in the same way as an assignment (§7.17.1) to the field or property.
>
> A member initializer that specifies an object initializer after the equals sign is a nested object initializer, i.e. an initialization of an embedded object. Instead of assigning a new value to the field or property, the assignments in the nested object initializer are treated as assignments to members of the field or property. Nested object initializers cannot be applied to properties with a value type, or to read-only fields with a value type.

Since your `Value` initializer is a nested initializer, it allows you to just assign members of `Value` without initializing it - as long as `Value` has been initialized already, of course. The compiler has no way of verifying whether `Value` is `null`, so it cannot give you an error.